# Do you get charged for requests that fail an APIG custom authorizer (unauthorized, rate limited)?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm looking to use an API Gateway Custom Authorizer to authorization.

If a user with an unauthorized token makes thousands/millions of tries will I get charged?

Comment: Why downvote this when there's little clear documentation about this online.

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread on the AWS Forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=274894&tstart=0

> Unauthorized calls are not charged to your account. You will be charged for any invocations of your custom authorizer, but these results are cached for a TTL that you can configure.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to leave a comment here as this is one of the top results when you search for this topic and that forum post is dead. I spoke to AWS Support and they confirmed that you *do not* pay for unauthed requests at the APIGW level, however you do pay for the authorizer lambda running the verification code:
[image]

To clarify:

1. Request comes in to API Gateway
2. Request is forwarded to Lambda custom authorizer
3. Request fails custom authorizer <-- You are charged for this lambda invocation
4. API Gateway rejects this request <-- You *are not* charged for this at the APIGW level

Answer (score 0):

For Custom Authorizer to authorization, you will get charged whether it pass or fail as it needs to get validated with API Gateway